# WampServer 3.0.6 Red Icon after windows update 01.01.2018

Tags: windows-10, wamp, wampserver

Windows 10 x64
WampServer 3.0.6

Everything was working perfect until 01.01.2018

I updated windows and today when i try wamp server not working.

WampIcon -> Right Click -> Tools -> Check state of services:

```
State of services:

The service 'wampapache64' is NOT started
 EXIT error code:1077
 Help message for error code 1077 is:
Son açıştan bu yana, hizmeti başlatma denemesi olmadı.

 The service 'wampmysqld64' is NOT started
 EXIT error code:1077
 Help message for error code 1077 is:
Son açıştan bu yana, hizmeti başlatma denemesi olmadı.

 The service 'dnscache' is started

WampServer (Apache, PHP and MySQL) will not function properly if any service
'wampapache64'
'wampmysqld64'
'dnscache'
 is not started.
```

searched some google and stackoverflow but no post about "error code 1077"

VC packages for wamp prerequisites were already installed

[image]

Don't using IIS or Skype.

[image]

port 80 is free

```
***** Test which uses port 80 *****

===== Tested by command netstat filtered on port 80 =====


Test for TCP
Port 80 is not found associated with TCP protocol
Port 80 is not found associated with TCP protocol

===== Tested by attempting to open a socket on port 80 =====

Your port 80 is not actually used.
```

Need your ideas what the problem is?

Should i reinstall wampserver???

Comment: Have you tried to manually start the service?  What error does that produce (in English) and what if any errors are displayed in the Event Viewer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the windows update may have removed the 2 services `wampapache64` and `wampmysqld64`

To get these re-installed is simple.

Using the menus on the Wampmanager icon do this:-

```
[left click] wampmanager->Apache->Service Administration-> Install Service
```

and

```
[left click] wampmanager->MySQL->Service Administration-> Install Service
```

or if you are using `MariaDB` then do

```
[left click] wampmanager->MariaDB->Service Administration-> Install Service
```

Comment: Vooww really good solution. But it worked for apache server, not for mysql server. Icon is orange now, not red. When i click MySQL->Service Administration-> Install Service nothing happened just disappear wamp menu. Nothing happening

Comment: Oops, i solved it. It was absurd solution for mysql but first i changed port 3307, manually clicked remove service under the mysql menu, changed again to 3306 then click install service, lastly clicked restart all servers and voila :) 
Thanks my herooooooo :):):):)

Comment: Thank you guys... had the exact same problem after a Windows update today and this answer and the comments below it helped me!